# Redis with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, redis-objects

I'm using Redis objects [hash_key](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects), in order to save a lot of email addresses. The key has set to a specific model.

```
  hash_key :emails, :global => true
```

If I use the following:

```
Committee.emails[1] = "mail@one.us, mail@two.com"
```

How long can my assigned email string become? I'd like to store a lot of addresses in this perhaps tens of thousands. Does this even make sense?

Comment: You're storing them for what purpose? Simply to print out? Or perhaps to iterate through and run some sort of logic from within Rails?

Comment: The purpose is to reduce joins, and to iterate through for UI logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value within a redis hash can be up to 512MB, so clearly you should be able to store far more emails than would likely be reasonable.

That said, if you can use a redis set instead, where each email is a separate set entry, you might save yourself a lot of CPU cycles building and parsing this massive string.